# Toast for invalid login not showing? Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making a login app with android. I'm trying to show a dialog that shows up whenever I enter an invalid credentials but it's not working? what Am i doing wrong?
I am able to log in fine though I just need the error toast

Code snippet

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Validating your Account", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    void login(){
        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",inputUsername.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",inputPassword.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            String username = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            switch(Integer.parseInt(response)){
                case 0:

                        session.createLoginSession(username);
                        Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        finish();
                    break;
                default:


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid username or password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    break;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat for invalid input

```
01-01 14:16:37.179: W/audio_hw_primary(111): out_write() limiting sleep time 32244 to 23219
01-01 14:16:47.699: W/audio_hw_primary(111): out_write() limiting sleep time 44149 to 23219
01-01 14:16:47.711: W/SingleClientConnManager(1571): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
01-01 14:16:47.711: W/SingleClientConnManager(1571): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
01-01 14:16:47.723: W/EGL_emulation(1571): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-01 14:16:47.723: W/audio_hw_primary(111): out_write() limiting sleep time 55759 to 23219
01-01 14:16:47.747: I/System.out(1571): Exception : Invalid int: ""
01-01 14:16:47.755: W/audio_hw_primary(111): out_write() limiting sleep time 27369 to 23219
01-01 14:16:47.927: W/InputMethodManagerService(472): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@53241ec4 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@533337e4
01-01 14:16:47.931: W/audio_hw_primary(111): out_write() limiting sleep time 25917 to 23219
```

Comment: I presume this is a part of asynctask?could please post more code to give a complete answer.

Comment: I posted more of the code. This isn't an asynctask though

Comment: you should look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).It will solve your issue

Comment: You are also not allowed to do UI related tasks on background threads.Like calling the intent too.Do you mind an AsyncTask related answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update **UI from a background thread**.It is **not possible**.

Use `AsyncTask` . Check login details in `doInBackground()`. Show the `Toast/AlertDialogue` in `onPostExecute()`.

[Here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/) is a nice example to learn the usage of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score -1):

add this to you activity

```
    private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    private int result=9;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",inputUsername.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",inputPassword.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            result=Integer.parseInt(response);
        return null;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected onPostExecute(){
        switch(Integer.parseInt(response)){
            case 0:
                session.createLoginSession(username);
                Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(b);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid username or password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

}

and this to you `onResume` or `onCreate`

```
 btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Validating your Account", true);
            new Login().execute()

        }
    });
```

and read about the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in Official docs and a [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/).

Comment: that was not me though

Comment: lol,I just asked in general.Try this solution and let me know if it works

Comment: Whenever I declare the variable for the session.createLoginSession(username); The onPostExecute() stopped being used. Any idea why?

Comment: cannot comment on that till you explain the session object.And which library is it